# Enable only Mondays and start with Monday in html5

Tags: php, html, date

I wrote a piece of code to disable future dates:

```
<input type="date" name="expens_date"  max="<?=date('Y-m-d')?>">
```

but here I need to enable only Mondays and week start on Monday.
Please help me. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an or (||) in there, like this:

```
beforeShowDay: function(date){
```

var day = date.getDay();

return [day == 1 || day == 1,""];

}

Comment: Are you using Jquery or only Javascript ?

Comment: only javascript